# Comparing today's date in Visual Basic with Date in MS Access Database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, date, oledb, datareader

The data type that I have used in Access is 'Date/Time'. I would like to know how I can extract the date in Access and assign it to a variable so I can compare both of them.

This is what I currently have. I set `'curdate'` to the current date. I want to do something like `'curdate = dbdate'` where `'dbdate'` represents the date in my database.

```
Dim curdate As Date
curdate = Date.Now()
```

How do I compare this with the date I have stored in my Access database?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

```
cmdCheckFines.CommandText = "Select * From Fines Where MemberID = '" & (txtMemberID.Text) & "';"
        cmdLoanDetails.CommandText = "Select * From Loan Where MemberID = " & (txtMemberID.Text) & ";"

        cmdCheckFines.Connection = cmOLEDB
        cmdLoanDetails.Connection = cmOLEDB

        Dim LoanDetails As OleDbDataReader = cmdLoanDetails.ExecuteReader()
        Dim CheckFines As OleDbDataReader = cmdCheckFines.ExecuteReader()

        If CheckFines.Read = True And LoanDetails.Read = True Then

            Dim fines As Integer
            Dim curdate As Date
            Dim expiryduration As Date

            curdate = Date.Now()
```

Comment: What have you tried to extract the date so far?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yup, but to no avail.

Comment: I asked what you have tried?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Sorry, my bad. I've tried to set the command text to filter the data and get the date from a specific row, but didn't work

Comment: Can you post said code without knowing more cant advise, and no-one on here will probably write it for you

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Alright, have edited it to what works so far, haven't found out how to retrieve the data though.

Comment: This is .net not vba, but you can extract the data from the datareaders

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Crystal ball says that you need curdate = Date.Now.Date

Comment: @HansPassant Currently trying to get oledbdatareader to get my data, but I don't know how. Any ideas?